# actualizar recurso en API REST

Tags: api, rest, postman

Hola estoy tratando de resolver el siguiente ejercicio y la verdad estoy un poco estancado.

"considerando las convenciones de una API REST, debes actualizar el recurso 'user' con id = 5. Para esto, deberás cambiar el nombre (name) del usuario a 'lemontech', si haces el cambio correcto la API te responderá con el siguiente paso."

esto es lo que estoy probando entre otras cosas que he probado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por favor si alguien me puede ayudar con esto, llevo todo un dia y no logo resolver lo.

Comment: Intenta con el path `/user/5`, no envies el `id` como un query param. Esa ruta junto con el segundo ejemplo (enviar `name` como json) debería ser suficiente para que funcione. Si no funciona, tal vez deberías revisar si la API tiene algún tipo de documentación en la que se especifíque cómo recibe los datos.

Comment: gracias Ricardo pero no funciono esa solución.